# Performant way to join 3D LiDAR mesh to 2D data

Tags: qgis, python, postgis

I'm new to 3D data and want to know what I should be searching for when I'm looking to find all the triangles in a 3D building mesh that fall within a 2D footprint.

The mesh comes from LiDAR and broken into 1km grids, the largest tile contains some 60m triangles there are 1,000 tiles to process.  I'm familiar with Python/QGIS/PostGIS and this seems like a problem others must have faced but I'm not getting any leads so think I'm not looking for the right terms where I've looked for `3D spatial joins in QGIS` and `generating 3D bounding box in QGIS from 2D polygon`

Comment: There are a bunch of [3D functions](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/3d.html#). If you are trying to find intersections with a 2D footprint, you can probably safely drop the z-coordinates, using ST_Forced2D. Or you could use [ST_3DIntersects(https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersects.html), but this will likely be much slower, even with a 3D spatial index.